# Pass & as a value in url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url, parameters

I am passing a value in url but some of my value contains & as a value this is a value:

```
 Transport, storage, communication & services related to broadcasting
```

When I am passing this value as a params url looks like this:

```
 test?search=Tertiary&year=2013-14&rain_fall_type=Transport,%20storage,%20communication%20&%20services%20related%20to%20broadcasting&compare=None&views=stackedColumn
```

My question is how to pass special characters through url and get that value as it is.

Comment: The ampersand is a URL reserved character, so it is being URL encoded. To get the original value you will need to URL decode it (for example you can use `decodeURIComponent()` in javascript)

Comment: so there is no way so I need to encode my string and pass that as encoded value and get  decode that value. My question is how ?

Comment: That URL from your question (`Transport,%20storage,` etc...) has already been encoded. To decode the value in Ruby, take a look at the `unescape` method http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `URI.encode('Transport, storage, communication & services related to broadcasting', /\W/)` in rails to encode special characters.

To decode the value `URI.decode(encoded_value)` will do the trick.

```
encoded_value = URI.encode('Transport & services', /\W/) # "Transport%20%26%20services"
URI.decode(encoded_value)                                # "Transport & services"
```

If you want to encode the same string in javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent('Transport & services')
```

Comment: I am passing this value from javascript so How can I encode this string in javascript and catch that param in rails and then decode.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can use `encodeURIComponent` in javascript and decode the value in rails with `URI.decode`. Of course the latter is unnecessary because rails takes care of that and decodes the string for you.